# Calculate Blue sky albedo from Black sky albedo and White sky albedo

Tags: remote-sensing, modis

I have got values for Black sky albedo and white sky albedo, from MODIS imagery. What is the simplest way to calculate blue sky albedo? I want to use albedo for snow cover.

A website which has listed this formula:

`Blue-sky (Actual) Albedo = White-sky Albedo * f(optical depth, solar zenith angle, aerosol type, band) + Black-sky Albedo * (1 - f(optical depth, solar zenith angle, aerosol type, band))`

Now the thing is I don't have solar zenith angle, aerosol type etc..

What do I do? Please help

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? I am presently facing the same problem. Even if I get optical depth, zenith angle, etc., what is the expression of the function? Arnab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solar zenith, you can use the [Solar Geom Calc](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/neubrew/SolarCalc.jsp?mu=on&sza=on&el=on&az=on).  Assuming you have access to the metadata for your imagery, or know the lat/long and date and time of image acquisition, you should be good to go.  As far as aerosol type, You should check out the [Modis site](http://modis-atmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/MOD04_L2/index.html) for more information.

Can you provide the link to the site where you got your formula?

Comment: Hi egdetti,
Thanks a lot for the reply.I got it from the website listed below. now my modis product is MCD43 A3 product, I'm not sure if I have time of acquisition, I do have the date for the images however.
http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS/MODIS-menu/MCD43.html